# L2TP/IPSec VPN Connection without encryption

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, l2tp, strongswan

My ISP provided us with VPN connection that comes with Gateway IP, Username & Password.
We connect through windows server 2016 fine with no issues

[Screenshot: Configuration of the VPN on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv0vC.jpg)

Now we want to switch to Ubuntu, but we are having issues connecting with IpSec/Strongswan

as the connection requires PSK or some kind of encryption

How can we connect using only user&pass

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you have configured a L2TP VPN connection without IPsec (i.e., no encryption).

On Ubuntu you can install the `network-manager-l2tp` and `network-manager-l2tp-gnome` packages. Don't enable IPsec in the IPsec Settings and in the PPP Settings disable all authentication methods other than **CHAP** and **MSCHAPv2**.

It seems crazy any ISP would be offering L2TP without IPsec. In the PPP Settings you could try enabling **Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)** so that it is using some encryption albeit weak.